# How to create glassfish-resources.xml and JDBC data source and connection pool in NetBeans 8.1?

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, glassfish-4.1

I was not able to create glassfish-resources.xml and JDBC data source and connection pool in NetBeans 8.1.

I followed the instructions from this page https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html  (section "Setting up a JDBC data source and connection pool"), but was not able to get those objects created.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue...BUT..there is no problem...because the file "glassfish-resources.xml" will appear/be located inside **Web Pages** -> **WEB-INF**..then drag the file into the **Server Resources** and finally right-click on the project **AffableBean** and click **Deploy**...

Then, you can check the **JDBC**